# Encountered an error when making Gremlin.Net communicate with JanusGraph in the JanusGraph official website.net introductory tutorial

Tags: c#, tinkerpop, janusgraph, gremlinnet

I tried to operate JanusGraph with .net using JanusGraph official [tutorial](https://docs.janusgraph.org/interactions/connecting/dotnet/), but got an error, the following is my code and .net\JanusGraph Error displayed by the server

I use vscode, the command to create a project is dotnet new console -o GremlinExample

Looks like I haven't added what I'm asking, but chatGPT thinks it's a result of neither the server nor the client getting the response they need, so I doubt it's something wrong with Gremlin.Net... ...

code：

```
using Gremlin.Net.Driver;
using Gremlin.Net.Driver.Remote;
using static Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.AnonymousTraversalSource;


Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");


var client = new GremlinClient(new GremlinServer("localhost", 8182));
// The client should be disposed on shut down to release resources
// and to close open connections with client.Dispose()
var g = Traversal().WithRemote(new DriverRemoteConnection(client));
        // Reuse 'g' across the application

Console.WriteLine("d!");

var herculesAge = g.V().Has("name", "hercules").Values<int>("age").Next();
Console.WriteLine($"Hercules is {herculesAge} years old.");
```

.net terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\Win10\GremlinExample> dotnet run
Hello, World!
d!
Unhandled exception. System.Text.Json.JsonException: '0x81' is an invalid start of a value. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: '0x81' is an invalid start of a value. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ConsumeValue(Byte marker)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadFirstToken(Byte first)
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.ReadSingleSegment()
   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.GetReaderScopedToNextValue(Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& state, JsonReaderException ex)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.GetReaderScopedToNextValue(Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Read[TValue](Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonTypeInfo`1 jsonTypeInfo)
   at Gremlin.Net.Structure.IO.GraphSON.GraphSONMessageSerializer.DeserializeMessageAsync(Byte[] message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.Connection.HandleReceivedAsync(Byte[] received)
   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.Connection.ReceiveMessagesAsync()
   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.ProxyConnection.SubmitAsync[T](RequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.GremlinClient.SubmitAsync[T](RequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.Remote.DriverRemoteConnection.SubmitBytecodeAsync(Guid requestid, Bytecode bytecode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Gremlin.Net.Driver.Remote.DriverRemoteConnection.SubmitAsync[S,E](Bytecode bytecode, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Remote.RemoteStrategy.ApplyAsync[S,E](ITraversal`2 traversal, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Utils.WaitUnwrap(Task task)
   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Remote.RemoteStrategy.Apply[S,E](ITraversal`2 traversal)
   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.DefaultTraversal`2.ApplyStrategies()
   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.DefaultTraversal`2.GetTraverserEnumerator()
   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.DefaultTraversal`2.get_TraverserEnumerator()
   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.DefaultTraversal`2.MoveNextInternal()
   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.DefaultTraversal`2.MoveNext()
   at Gremlin.Net.Process.Traversal.DefaultTraversal`2.Next()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\Win10\GremlinExample\Program.cs:line 17
```

JanusGraph server：

```
05:30:56 INFO  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.GremlinServer$1.operationComplete - Channel started at port 8182.
05:31:03 WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder.select - Gremlin Server is not configured with a serializer for the requested mime type [application/vnd.gremlin-v3.0+json] - using org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1 by default
05:31:03 WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder.decode - Serialization error while decoding request
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.SerializationException: The most significant bit should be set according to the format
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.binary.RequestMessageSerializer.readValue(RequestMessageSerializer.java:45) ~[gremlin-driver-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1.deserializeRequest(GraphBinaryMessageSerializerV1.java:175) ~[gremlin-driver-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder.decode(WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder.java:77) [gremlin-server-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder.decode(WsGremlinBinaryRequestDecoder.java:43) [gremlin-server-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.Utf8FrameValidator.channelRead(Utf8FrameValidator.java:89) [netty-codec-http-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) [netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) [netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
05:31:03 WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.OpSelectorHandler.decode - Invalid OpProcessor requested [null]
org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.op.OpProcessorException: Invalid OpProcessor requested [null]
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.OpSelectorHandler.decode(OpSelectorHandler.java:85) [gremlin-server-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.handler.OpSelectorHandler.decode(OpSelectorHandler.java:48) [gremlin-server-3.6.2.jar:3.6.2]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:88) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.Utf8FrameValidator.channelRead(Utf8FrameValidator.java:89) [netty-codec-http-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318) [netty-codec-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286) [netty-handler-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) [netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
05:31:06 WARN  io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.onUnhandledInboundException - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:259) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:151) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562) [netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) [netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_202]
05:31:06 WARN  io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.onUnhandledInboundException - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_202]
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBuf.setBytes(PooledByteBuf.java:259) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.89.Final.jar:4.1.89.Final]
```

Comment: Please take care when adding tags. There is no C code shown in your question. C and C# are very different languages.

Comment: @Gerhardh
sorry my fault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
 dotnet add package Gremlin.Net
```

instead of

```
dotnet add package Gremlin.Net -v 3.5.5
```

to upgrade Gremlin.Net to the latest version, now the problem has been alleviated